# Can anyone explain why the JUnit test is giving an error?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, junit

I'm writing a piece of code involving matrices.My code for ArrayMatrix compiled without any errors however when I try to run a JUnit test on the code I get an error. At this point I'm unsure if I have even done this right.

```
public class ArrayMatrix extends AbstractMatrix{

    private double[][] elements;

    public ArrayMatrix(final int rows, final int columns) throws MatrixException{
     // Initialise a new matrix with all the elements set to 0.0
        if (rows < 0 || columns < 0) {
            throw new MatrixException("Negative rows or columns are not allowed");
        }
        double[][] elements = new double[rows][columns];
        int i,j;
        for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            for (j=0;j<columns;j++) {
                elements[i][j]= 0.0;             
            }        
        }
    }
    public ArrayMatrix(double[][] content) throws MatrixException{
 // Initialise a new matrix storing the data provided by the
 // double[][] parameter. Note the data should be copied.
        int rows = elements.length;
        int columns = elements[0].length;
        int i,j;
        for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<columns;j++) {
                content[i][j] = elements[i][j];
            }
        }

    }
    public int getNumberOfRows(){
 // Number of rows in matrix
        int noRows = elements.length;
        return noRows;
    }
    public int getNumberOfColumns(){
 // Number of columns in matrix
        int noColumns = elements[0].length;
        return noColumns;
    }
    public double getElement(final int row, final int column) throws MatrixException{
         // Return the element at the specified position or throw an exception
        if (elements.length<=row) {
            throw new MatrixException("Attempt to access invalid element ("+row+","+column+")");
        }
        if (elements[0].length<column){ 
            throw new MatrixException("Attempt to access invalid element ("+row+","+column+")");
        }
        else {return elements[row][column];}
    }

    public void setElement(final int row, final int column, final double value) throws MatrixException{
         // Set the element at the specified position or throw an exception
        if (elements.length<=row) {
             throw new MatrixException("Attempt to access invalid element ("+row+","+column+")");}
        if (elements[0].length<column){ 
             throw new MatrixException("Attempt to access invalid element ("+row+","+column+")");}
        else {elements[row][column] = value;}
         }
}
```

This is the JUnit test I wrote:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetNumberOfRows() throws MatrixException {
        ArrayMatrix a = new ArrayMatrix(2, 2);
        int output = a.getNumberOfRows();
        assertEquals(2,output);
```

have i written the JUnit test incorrectly?

Comment: Well, for starters, "what errors"? And what is the *minimum code* that causes these "errors"?

Comment: I suspect *an* issue is the **field** called `elements` is *not initialized* in due to it being *shadowed* in the `ArrayMatrix(final int rows, final int columns)` ctor. The non-tested `ArrayMatrix(double[][] content)` is also suspect for accessing said *not initialized* field.

Comment: No errors during compilation however the JUnit test fails saying that there is an error on line 35 ( the section on getNumberOfRows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `getNumberOfRows()` method throws a `NullPointerException`. This is because you don't initialize the MatrixArrays's `elements` array in the constructor and it stays `null`, and the exception is thrown when you are trying to access the property (`length`) of a null.

Instead you have created a *new, local variable* with `double[][] elements = new double[rows][columns];` in the constructor, which is not probably intended.

Replace that row with the reference to the MatrixArray's field (in the constructor): `this.elements = new double[rows][columns];`. Now the `elements` array is initialised and you should be able to access its fields without exceptions.

As a side note, you have a similar issue in your constructor `ArrayMatrix(double[][])`: You should take a look at that as well.